# React native wont compile on Android device but will on emulator

Tags: android, react-native

[image: React native error screenshot]

TypeError inside of index.android.bundle

I have this error when running my React native on my physical android device but everything works perfectly on any android emulator i've tried. I don't really know what can I do since this error is in the bundle so i'm at a loss at where to really fix this error.